# Printing first index in array prints every index with C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am starting to learn C and have a question about arrays.

Here I have a 2-dimensional simple array of characters:

```
char memory[100][6];
...
// populate indexes
```

and here I try to print out the first row:

```
puts(memory[0]);
```

Here is the output. Why does every row print out?

```
00P00300P10404P1ZZZZ0000ZZ0010
```

I come from Java where if you run the same code you will only get the first row. Am I missing something or is this just how C handles arrays? If so, how can I just get the first row?

Comment: Garbage is displayed because it is not initialized

Comment: The output is not garbage. Every 6 characters is an array element. I just hide the populating code.

Comment: `puts` expects a string. A C string is by definition a sequence of characters terminated by `\0` (NUL). So it's not a property of C overall but a property of `puts` and how it is defined to behave. If you want to print a single character you would not use `puts` but something else, for instance: `printf("%c", memory[0][0])`.

Comment: Would I use `printf`, and with what type?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing more of your initialization code. My guess is that you're not appending a null character to the end of your character arrays. C-style string output functions such as puts() and fputs() rely on strings being null terminated. If you know the size of all your strings you could try another function such as write()

Comment: @Nic If you want to print a single character you can use kaylum's specifier. If you want to print a string you can use <code>printf("%s\n", memory[0])</code>. You can include or omit the newline character <code>'\n'</code> depending on what kind of output you want.

Comment: @David All my strings are the same size.

Comment: @Nic It sounds like you don't actually have any strings - you just have arrays of 6 char

Comment: @M.M Yes that is true.

Comment: `puts` is for outputting strings; so you either have to store strings in your array, or use a different output function. Such as `printf("%.6s", memory[0]);`

Comment: I would prefer to access via row and not character count because I do not want to calculate the amount of characters each time. My array does not include a terminator however. Using `printf` is completely fine, I just only want the index I'm asking for, not the entire array.

Comment: @Nic Then you'll have to write code that knows how to do something with an array row. That strikes me as a lot of effort for very little payoff. Instead, why not either use C-style strings or use characters? Those are both already there and both have lots of nice functions that know what to do with them.

Comment: What exactly do you think should be printed by `puts(memory[0])`?  If the answer is `00P003`, then you have not created null terminated strings and that is the problem.  If you think it should be something shorter, then we need to see how you initialize the array; there are multiple ways to get it wrong and we're not able to guess which one you've chosen to use.  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Reduce the dimension from 100 to no more than 10 (5 would be sufficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `puts` function is strictly for C-style strings. If you pass it a pointer to something other than a C-style string, garbage is likely to result. How are you expecting it to know how many characters to output?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the entirety of my question because I am also wondering how to get a given index in my array by value. Such as `memory[0]`. I do not have any "string terminators" because as stated by others I have an array of characters.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "get a given index in my array by value". If you want array[2][3], use `array[2][3]`. Just don't use `puts`.

Comment: I don't want `array[2][3]`. I want `array[2]`.

Comment: @Nic Then you'll have to write code that understands how to do something with an array row, because even if you had `array[2]`, what could you do with it? You have no code that takes it. So why paint yourself into a corner?

Comment: @Nic: You say that you don't want to have a terminator, but also that you don't want to calculate the number of characters. You can't have both of these things, you'll have to choose one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Paul. I was not aware of this. I come from higher level languages and this makes more sense now.